# CloudWatch PutMetricData value range

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-cloudwatch-metrics

[According to the documentation](https://docs.amazonaws.cn/en_us/AmazonCloudWatch/latest/APIReference/API_MetricDatum.html):

> Although the parameter accepts numbers of type Double, CloudWatch rejects values that are either too small or too large. Values must be in the range of 8.515920e-109 to 1.174271e+108 (Base 10) or 2e-360 to 2e360 (Base 2). In addition, special values (for example, NaN, +Infinity, -Infinity) are not supported.

The range of valid values does not include zero, or negative values.

Elsewhere, the documentation states that [you can choose to publish the value zero](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonCloudWatch/latest/monitoring/publishingMetrics.html), and this seems to be confirmed by experience.

Can anyone explain this apparent inconsistency, and also explain why the restriction on the range of valid values?  I can understand why NaN, PositiveInfinity and NegativeInfinity would be excluded, but not why other values would be.